# How can I solve Bad Request error 400 in React?

Tags: spring-boot

When I send this request from Postman to SpringBoot, it works.

```
        "location": "New Jersey",
        "category": {
            "name": "Travel",
            "id": 1
        },
        "expensedate": "2020-03-17",
        "descript": "New York City"

}
```

But, when I post request from ReactJS, it says **400 Bad Request**

```
const item1={
            descript : event.target.description.value,
            category:{
                 id:1, name:event.target.category.value
             },
            expensedate : event.target.date.value,
            location : event.target.location.value
        }
        console.log(event.target.category.key);
        console.log(item1)


        await fetch(`/api/expenses`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
            body: JSON.stringify(item1)
        })
```

SpringBoot

```
@PostMapping("/expenses")
    Expense  createExpense(@RequestBody Expense expense){
        return this.expenseRepository.save(expense);
    }
```

Comment: any traces from spring-boot on this?

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(item1)) as this is the most important here (or just check in browser console)

Comment: Please add the full stack trace for the bad request. Spring usually outputs why it is a bad request